# Having Trouble Installing GitFlow

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm having problem installing gitflow. I am using this tutorial: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/installing-git-flow-in-windows/

I'm stuck at Step 3

When I run `git clone git://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git -–recursive` I got this result:

```
Cloning into 'gitflow'...
remote: Counting objects: 1407, done.
emote: Total 1407 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1407
Receiving objects: 100% (1407/1407), 623.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (689/689), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
error: unable to create file contrib/msysgit-install.cmd (Permission denied)
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

I've also looked up the comments in the site for some answers but I can't find answers.

Comment: This sounds like an SSH problem to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: when cloning, one creates only files locally, since the error is to create a file, I think this is about access rights.

Comment: @AustinImperial: What are the access rights on the directory? `git` should be able to create files withing the directory.

Comment: Thanks CommSoft and Tim Biegeleisen for the tips! Appreciated it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an answer

Run the code `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` or `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` for you to go in the directory `/usr/bin` and then run the code `git clone git://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git -–recursive`.

If it doesn't work still, try running git bash as an administrator. (Right-click the bash icon in the desktop and click `Run as Administrator`)

Comment: @AusinImperial You can also mark this answer correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't mark it correct... it says that I need to wait 2 days